# 503 Backend Error from Google Analytics v3

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I am trying to get analytics with **`ga:pageviews`** and **`ga:pagePath=~^/dr/`** as a filter I am getting the following issue. (using Google Analytics API V3)

Output: It should return all the **urls** from my site with **pageviews**. ( From 2008 - 2013 )

```
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
```

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503
>   Service Unavailable

Can anybody help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Happens when the google is unable to process your request. If you have lots of traffic between 2008-2013, then try breaking it up so that the google can process.

But if you're still seeing error with small date range with few metrics and dimensions set, then implement exponential backup algo to fetch data as recommended here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors

Otherwise, upgrade to premium and ask for your money back when the google not performing :)